# Outlook doesn't recognise changed primary mail address in exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

I changed my primary mail address in Exchange (Office365) but Outlook uses still my old one. How can I synchronise them?

Comment: Please explain how you have confirmed Outlook is using the old address. Have you inspected the headers of a message sent from Outlook?

Comment: Outlook still shows the old one in the account settings and in the from field while creating a new mail which is also seen by the recipient.

Comment: Try sending yourself a message to another email account. Does it still show the old address in that case in the From field? (It's best to inspect the message headers.)

Comment: Yes it does show the old one.

Comment: Then it seems the change has not taken effect on the Exchange server. In an Exchange environment, the definition of the default address for an account is not up to Outlook.

Comment: I just tried it with OWA and there it is also still the old one. So I think your right that exchange actually hasn’t changed it. Any clue how I can force exchange to take effect?

Comment: the change takes effect *immediately* when done on the server. This suggests the change was not saved. I'd double-check the setting on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out that this behaviour is by design:

> Cause
>
> This issue is by design. The email address that's stamped in the root folder is determined at the time of profile creation and should reflect the primary SMTP address that's stamped on the user. The email address is strictly cosmetic and cannot be changed when the user's primary SMTP email address changes.
>
> Workaround
>
> To work around this issue, delete and then re-create the profile for the user.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3040795/smtp-address-in-user-s-profile-doesn-t-change-when-primary-email-addre

Comment: Good point. I hope now it's better?